# how can I $_POST this below

Tags: php, javascript

Below is my javascript and form code where it appends a question number (qnum) for each table row appended in the application one by one. So if user adds a table row then it contains question number 1, when second row is added, question number 2 is added, then 3 for third row and etc.

```
<script>

    function insertQuestion(form) {   

        var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
        var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
        var $qid = $("<td class='qid'>" + qnum + "</td>");

        $tr.append($qid);
        $tbody.append($tr); 

        ++qnum;
        $("#questionNum").text(qnum);

</script>


<form id="QandA" action="insertQuestion.php" method="post" >

<div id="detailsBlock">
    <table id="question">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
                Question Number <span id="questionNum">1</span>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

The problem I have is that I want to do a `$_POST` in the next page for all the question numbers added. The only problem is that because I am not using an input field, I do not have a name attribute to `$_POST`. so what I want to know is that if I can use 'name' attribute to `$_POST`, then how else can I post the question numbers?

Comment: what about appending hidden input to your form in insertQuestion function?

Comment: @ocanal I have added a hidden input here:  `var $qid = $("<td class='qid'><input type='hidden' name='numQuestion' >" + qnum + "</td>");` The good thing is that there is no notice for $_POST['numQuestion'], the bad news though is that it does not recieve a question number, it just recieves a blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. Add a hidden field to your markup. Hidden variables are posted back to the server and are available in $_POST with their name. I have added the 2 lines starting with ** and ending with **

```
<script>

    function insertQuestion(form) {   

        var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
        var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
        var $qid = $("<td class='qid'>" + qnum + "</td>");

        $tr.append($qid);
            $tbody.append($tr); 

        ++qnum;
        $("#questionNum").text(qnum);
        **$("#num_questions").val(qnum);**

</script>


<form id="QandA" action="insertQuestion.php" method="post" >
**<input type="hidden" id ="num_questions" value="" name="num_questions">**
<div id="detailsBlock">
    <table id="question">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
                Question Number <span id="questionNum">1</span>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

answer for your question and your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983559/how-can-i-post-this-below#comment12757946_9983559)

> @ocanal I have added a hidden input here: var $qid = $("" + qnum + ""); The good thing
>   is that there is no
>   notice for $_POST['numQuestion'], the bad news though is that it does
>   not recieve a
>   question number, it just recieves a blank

yes it recieves a blank because you are not assigning value for your hidden input.

you should do it like this,

```
var $qid = $("<td class='qid'><input type='hidden' name='numQuestion[]' 
              value='" + qnum +"' >" 
              + qnum + "</td>");
```

After posting form you will get numQuestion values as array.

for example,

```
print_r($_POST["numQuestion"]);
```

will print this,

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could, in theory, take the information that you need to have on the next page, then use javascript to dynamically create  elements with the proper name="" and value="" pairs in order to make them be sent to the backend server. That's one way to do it at least.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding hidden fields which are not visible, but contain the information you would like.  You can use CSS to hide the field.  These fields would be made of the regular things you find in a form like a < input type=text >

Answer (score 0):

Could you `$_POST` each line via Ajex every time one is added and store it in the `$_SESSION`?